# How do I switch the app store region on Apple TV?

Tags: apple-id, appletv, internationalization

I recently moved from Japan to the USA. Now I'm trying to use my Apple TV in the USA. When I go to the store and try to install an app it says "You can't use this account on the Japanese store. Before purchasing, switch to the USA store"

The region on my Apple TV is set to USA in Settings->General. Checking my Apple account on my iPhone by going to Settings->Name->Media and Purchases->Show Account->Country/Region shows my Apple account is set to USA

How do I get Apple TV to use the USA store?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I solved it by removing my account on Apple TV and adding it back after I changed my account on another device.

It's the same account. Sounds like a bug